# Why does when I ask for a value in an input, and put in that input it does not return the value i want

Tags: python

When I run this code and put in 15 as my input, why does it say you are older than me when I specifically told Python when the input is 15 to print you are my exact age.

```
age=input("What is your age?")

if int(age) >= 15:
  print("Your older than me!")

elif int(age) <= 15:
  print("Your younger than me!")

elif int(age) == 15:
  print("Your my exact age!")
```

Comment: You are using >= - and 15 is >= 15 (>= means greater than or equal to). You need to use > (greater than).

Comment: Think about your first `if`.  15 *is* greater than or equal to 15, so it prints "older".  The remaining `elif` are skipped once the first true statement is found.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first if statement you have will evaluate true when age is 15, that is because `>=` checks for greater or equal. You can change that to just `>`. That also goes for `<=`, this will check for less or equal. So age <= 15 will evaluate to true. Change that to only `<`

Comment: Im an idiot thank you so much

Answer (score 3):

you placed `<=` and `>=` statements, the equal in those means bigger/smaller or equal to X.
in your code you need to replace them with > and < because you already have an equal statement.